# Test if an array is part of an array of arrays and delete it

Tags: python, arrays, python-3.x, numpy

I have the following array of arrays:

```
import numpy as np
a = [np.array([52.941, 57.962]),
 np.array([52.918, 57.96 ]),
 np.array([52.908, 57.958]),
 np.array([52.898, 57.957]),
 np.array([52.878, 57.953]),
 np.array([52.868, 57.952]),
 np.array([52.813, 57.941])]
```

Now I want to test if the array `test = np.array([52.908, 57.958])` is part of the arrays mentioned above and delete if it is part of the array.

How can I check this and delete it ?

I tried:

```
if test in a:
    print('okay')
```

and

```
a.remove(test)
```

... but it doesn't work.

I get the following error:

> ValueError: The truth value of an array with more than one element is
>   ambiguous. Use a.any() or a.all()

What does it mean ?

Answer (score 3):

Using a **list** of arrays prevents you from taking advantage of NumPy's vectorisation capabilities. You can convert to a single array, and this resolves your problem:

```
a = np.array(a)

if test in a:
    print('match found!')
```

But at this point you can index with a Boolean array:

```
res = a[~(a == test).all(1)]

array([[ 52.941,  57.962],
       [ 52.918,  57.96 ],
       [ 52.898,  57.957],
       [ 52.878,  57.953],
       [ 52.868,  57.952],
       [ 52.813,  57.941]])
```

If you are concerned about floating point approximations, you can use [`np.allclose`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.allclose.html) with [`np.apply_along_axis`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.1/reference/generated/numpy.apply_along_axis.html):

```
def test_close(b):
    return np.allclose(test, b)

res = a[~np.apply_along_axis(test_close, 1, a)]
```

Comment: Thanks ! ...and how do I delete it ?

Comment: @james, That's exactly what the logic in my answer does, it removes matching rows via the Boolean array. `False` means remove, `True` means keep.

Comment: I see. thanks ! Hmm... I get the error: "numpy.ndarray not callable"

Comment: I don't quite understand: You don't call any variables in your test_close() definition for res at the end ?